# How to implement the edit comment in Facebook?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

This's my activity :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efcZc.png)
When the "E" button clicked which refers to Edit i want change the two Texts Views to be Edit texts and the "E" changes to SAVE button.

this is the way i'm thinking to implement the Edit operation ,,

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of using TextView use editText enable disable as Button click. In First state make is Enable false on E button click make it Enable True and change the button Text E to Save, then clicking on button Again Make editText Enable false and change the button Text from Save to E

Answer (score 0):

I did it using :

textView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);